# Spring aspect not applied to for ServiceFactoryBean created bean

Tags: spring, aop, serviceloader

I'm having problem applying aspect to ServiceFactoryBean-created (ServiceLoader-loaded) bean.

My spring context looks something like this:

```
...
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>

<bean id="myBean"
      class="org.springframework.beans.factory.serviceloader.ServiceFactoryBean"
      p:serviceType="com.test.MyInterface"/>

<bean id="myAnotherBean"
      class="com.test.MyAnotherBean"/>
```

My aspect is defined as follows:

```
@Aspect
public class MyAspect {

    @Pointcut("bean(myBean)")
    public void foo() {
    }

    @Pointcut("bean(myAnotherBean)")
    public void bar() {
    }

    @Around("foo()")
    public Object doFoo(final ProceedingJoinPoint jp) throws Throwable {
        return timed(jp, "foo");
    }

    @Around("bar()")
    public Object doBar(final ProceedingJoinPoint jp) throws Throwable {
        return timed(jp, "bar");
    }

    private ThreadLocal<StopWatch> stopWatch = new ThreadLocal<StopWatch>();

    private Object timed(final ProceedingJoinPoint jp, final String taskName) throws Throwable {
        stopWatch.get().add(taskName);
        try {
            return jp.proceed();
        } finally {
            if (stopWatch.get() != null) {
                stopWatch.get().stop(taskName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For some unknown reason, the aspect is only applied to myAnotherBean's calls but not to myBean's call.
Any ideas ?

Comment: Is the call to myBean which is not being advised a self-invocation?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by smp7d in the comments to your question, Spring created proxies can only have advice applied to them if the method call is coming from another object. Self-invocation isn't enough to trigger the advice.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/spring-framework-reference/html/ch08s06.html

```
public class Main {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      ProxyFactory factory = new ProxyFactory(new SimplePojo());
      factory.addInterface(Pojo.class);
      factory.addAdvice(new RetryAdvice());

      Pojo pojo = (Pojo) factory.getProxy();

      // this is a method call on the proxy!
      pojo.foo();
   }
}
```

The key thing to understand here is that the client code inside the main(..) of the Main class has a reference to the proxy. This means that method calls on that object reference will be calls on the proxy, and as such the proxy will be able to delegate to all of the interceptors (advice) that are relevant to that particular method call. However, once the call has finally reached the target object, the SimplePojo reference in this case, any method calls that it may make on itself, such as this.bar() or this.foo(), are going to be invoked against the this reference, and not the proxy. This has important implications. It means that self-invocation is not going to result in the advice associated with a method invocation getting a chance to execute.